# How to use 'before_action' in a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, rubygems

I would like to use 'before_action' in a module.

Unfortunately, I couldn't get it work.

I was googleing, but everything I found couldn't solve the problem.

My module file looks like the following:

```
module ShowController
  include SimpleController
  #before_action :set_object, only: [:show]

  def show
   set_object
  end
end
```

I would like to use the outcommented before_action line instead of the show method.

Therefore, I was trying to include the following modules:

```
  include AbstractController::Callbacks
  include ActiveSupport::Callbacks
  include ActiveSupport::Concern
  include ActiveSupport
```

Additionally, I tried to "require 'active_support/all'" or the core_ext.

The error_message I receive is:

```
 undefined method `class_attribute' for SimpleController::ShowController:Module
```

Finally, nothing worked out and I didn't find a solution.

Comment: If you're getting `undefined method 'class_attribute'` you probably need to make ShowController a class and not a module.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
class SomeController < ActionController::Base
  include SimpleController
end 

module SimpleController
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :set_object, only: [:show]
  end
end
```

Comment: I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'before_action' for MyModel(id: uuid, name: string):Class  Did you mean?  before_commit` with having this inside my `MyModel` controller concern.

Comment: My example was for use in a Controller, not a Model. If you're using this in a Model, then you can use ActiveRecord callbacks like before_commit or after_save etc.

Comment: Sorry I explained it a bit bad - I actually did it in controller concern but I now discovered that I accidentally named the controller concern with same name as my other model concern so that gave me errors :P My bad.

Comment: But if I then run before_action :set_object, only: [:something] in SomeController does this overwrite the prior before_action or not?  It is stated that it doesn't if this was outright inheritance but the included do just executes the resulting code in the class no so later before_actions do...??