# Rails: DRYing up before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a few controllers:

```
class First < ApplicationController
   before_action: do_this
   before_action: do_this_too
end

class Second < ApplicationController
  before_action: do_this
  before_action: do_this_too
end

class Third < ApplicationController

end
```

Two of the controllers have the same `before_action`'s method. How do I dry up this code so that the `First` and `Second` class use the `before_action`'s in one location but not the `Third` class?

I am thinking of some kind of class inheritance solution. Any ideas? In my real world example I have more classes with multiple identical `before_actions` on each?

Comment: You could create a module defining these `before_action` callbacks and include this module in every controller that need it, or use inheritance and create a parent controller

Comment: Will I not get undefined method before_action ? Isn't before action a class method? If not, where do I put it?

Comment: You can find an example right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867124/how-to-use-before-action-in-a-module

Comment: Don't and just leave it be. It's clear, it's obvious, it's simple. Putting it in a module does *not* improve things. Is `include BeforeActions` +  that file really better than two lines? IMHO it isn't. Since this example is very abstract, one thing you could do is make a third `do_both` method which calls `do_this` and `do_this_foo`. But this would only make sense if those methods "belong" together somehow (i.e. `:do_this_and_foo`).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I know man, I know. You are preaching to the choir. I didn;t ask if it was better, I asked how to do it. I agree 100% with you and the following commenters.

Comment: Totally agree with @Carpetsmoker - DRY is not a religion to be obsessively pursued.  It is just one guiding principle and it should be balanced with other principles such as readability.  As it is, your code makes perfect sense to someone else (eg a colleague) who comes along and reads it.  If it involved lots of repeated logic then DRY it, if it's a short simple list like this then it tells you what you need to know about what's different in each controller and so does it's job well.

Comment: If the `before_action` is the same across several controllers (not just 2 or 3), then IMO you should create a Module and include it. It will be a nightmare to update the `before_action` implementation and be sure that the X different definitions are the same. Duplicate code is also a source of trouble guys

Answer (score 4):

I believe that it's better to keep it the way it is. If you move these `before_action` to a module or something like that it will make your controller a lot harder to read and  to understand what's happening.

In other words, you would DRY your controllers, but would also violate the KISS principle (Keep It Simple).

But if you want to do this anyway, here's how:

```
module SharedBeforeActions
  def self.included(base)
    base.before_action :do_this
  end

  def do_this
    # Your filter definition here
  end
end

class Third < ApplicationController
  include SharedBeforeActions
end
```

Finally you would have to config Rails to load your module:

```
# config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Comment: You mentioned it in the text of your answer but not the code. I believe `before_action` is the preferred method now.

Comment: Thanks @yez, I forgot to change it